# Plant identification: Japanese barberry?

Tags: identification, shrubs, landscaping

Based on Bing Image search, this looks like Japanese barberry. If it matters, we live in western Massachusetts.

[image: Japanese barberry?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this looks very much like *Berberis thunbergii* "Atropurpurea". It's a tough plant that can be cut hard back if it gets too big. Mind the prickles.

Comment: tough is an understatement, only plant I know that can be dug out of the ground, put out  for garbage, replanted and will thrive